# Rails polymorphic association with connection table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a table called recipes and another called ingredients.  Ingredients can either connect to foods or recipes (one recipe can contain other recipes).  I have implemented it with the food part of it but I'm not sure how to implement the recipe part of it.  I created another table called the food part of it called recipe_as_ingredients which I will neet to populate when a recipe is saved with the recipes selected as ingredients in the current recipe.  I would probably have to update the table before each save and manually delete lines if deleted for the recipes.  Is there a better way of implemnting it?

Here are the models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :recipe
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, :as => :element
end

class RecipeAsIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, :as => :element
end
```

I manually set the element type in a function before saving so I would need to to similar for a recipe as ingredient but make sure that recipe_as_ingredient contains a record to connect to the ingredient:

```
self.element_id = numid.id
self.element_type = 'Food'
```

p.s. I could not connect the recipe without the recipe_as_ingredients connection tables because it made saving the record impossible because recipe was both a master record and detail record and the id field was always nil.

Answer (score 0):

You're so close.

Move:
   has_many :ingredients, :as => :element

Onto the Recipe model.

RecipeAsIngrident should exist. If you want to get all the Foods used in the recipe then you want a function on Recipe to sum up the descendants. This would be a calculated total, so you wouldn't need callbacks for updating totals etc, however I would add logic to prevent a recipe being deleted which is used for something else.

Ask if you need more clarification.

Comment: Hello.  When I move this line to the Recipe model all the ingredient lines get corrupted when I save a recipe so it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have existing data then you might need to alter it to conform to the new spec. provided you have 'recipe a' and 'food a' in the db already, try running this in console: `r = Recipe.new` ;`r.ingredients.build([{element: Recipe.first, quantity: 1}, {element: Food.first, quantity: 1}])`; `r.save!`